# SQL Select with Like String Contains ' '

Tags: mysql, sql

Who can tell me how we select like this in SQL?

```
"SELECT 
       name 
  FROM tablename 
 WHERE name LIKE 'at' ase'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Escape the quote with a backslash (\).

```
SELECT name FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE 'et\' demor'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select name from tablename where name like 'at\' ase'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape it using backslash \ . Like so,

```
"select name from tablename where name like 'et\' demor' "
```

Answer (score 1):

Use backslash:

```
"SELECT 
      name 
 FROM tablename 
 WHERE name like 'et\' demor' "
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape it using a backslash:

```
select name from tablename where name like 'at\' ase';
```

Your code defeats the purpose of using like, since your code achieve the same result as an `=` operator. You may use the query below instead (notice the `%`):

```
select name from tablename where name like '%at\' ase%';
```

The `%` there serves as a wildcard symbol in selecting result. Thus it will select all `name` that contains the string `at' ase` in any part of the `name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want { at' asc } in Like within a string dynamically then use below

```
'select name from tablename where name like ''%at'''' asc%'''
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this out.**

SELECT * FROM test.categories where name like "at' ase'";